# Выделение причастия запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Правильно ли выделено запятыми причастие "соответствующие":
*В данной лекции лектор дал три новых метода по разделам, соответствующим, – это введение в курс, методы и практика*.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно непонятная фраза. Место слова "соответствующим" перед словом "разделам" - "В данной лекции лектор дал три новых метода по соответствующим разделам: это введение в курс, методы и практика". 
Но совершенно непонятно, как можно дать метод, и лучше не "соответствующим" (чему??), а по следующим разделам.

Comment: Лучше бы это пособие не дошло до читателей.

Comment: "Плюс многа". И хорошо еще, если это пособие по пожарно-прикладному бегу в мешках, а ну как по русскому языку?!

Answer (score 0):

Фраза настолько неграмотна, что о запятых говорить не приходится.
Даже не могу представить, что она вообще может значить - и чему соответствовать.

Comment: Да, согласен, что фраза для русского языка не очень грамотна. Но фраза взята из пособия, которое нужно проверить. Поэтому и возник вопрос о запятых. Не обращайте внимание на смысл - просто  рассмотрите с точки зрения обособления такого причастия.

Comment: Так смысл же непонятен, а следовательно и грамматика. 
Да и необходимость обособления может зависеть от смысла.
Нельзя же взять случайный набор несвязанных слов - а потом спрашивать, как знаки расставить. Я ж даже не спрашиваю, что такое "дать метод" или являются ли эти "введение" и "практика" названиями разделов.
Но интересующее вас "соответствующим" - оно-то к чему относится?
Тут ещё такая штука есть: при сочетании тире и запятой запятая частенько опускается - и это тоже может зависеть от смысла.